# Get Wordpress the_title() in unencoded form

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the the my posts title in my single.php in an unencoded format. I have tried using `the_title();`, `the_title_attribute();` and `html_entity_decode(the_title());` however all still encode characters like &.

Can someone tell me what the correct syntax is to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id, 'raw' );
```

This will provide the raw unfiltered title.

Answer (score 1):

Get the current `WP_Post` object using `get_post()`. Then access the `title` property of the `WP_Post` object instance. This gives you the raw title value as entered via the WP Dashboard.

```
<?php
$post = get_post();
$raw_title = $post->post_title;
```

Comment: Code only answers may solve the original question, but an explanation of what your answer does and how it achieves the required results would help others understand the solution.